# NullPointerException: radixSort

Tags: java, radix-sort

```
import java.lang.Math;




public class radixSort{
    public static int getFreeSpace(Integer array[]){        //this function gets the first occurence of a null element in the array
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < array.length;i++){
            if (array[i] == null){
                break;
            }
        }
        return i;
    }
    public static Integer[] flatten(Integer array[][]){    //this function flattens the multi-dimensional lsdArray to a single dimension array
        Integer finalArray[] = new Integer[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            Integer[] currentArray = array[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < currentArray.length; j++){
                if (array[i][j] != null){
                    int index = getFreeSpace(finalArray); 
                    finalArray[index] = currentArray[j];
                                        
                }
                else;     
                                         
            }

            
            
        }
        return finalArray;
    }
    public static Integer getMaxDigits(Integer array[]){    //this function gets the largest number of digits in the array. this is helplful for getting the number of times the array is passed into the sort
        Integer max = 0;
        Integer m = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            m = Math.max(max, array[i]);
        }
        String s = m.toString();
        return s.length();
    }

    public static Integer[] radixSortFunc(Integer array[],Integer maxDigits, Integer counter){ //the sorting algorithm
        Integer[][] lsdArray = new Integer[10][15];
        if (counter <= maxDigits){
            
            for (Integer i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
                double temp = Math.pow(10,counter+1);
                int powOfTen = (int) temp;
                int term = (array[i] % powOfTen );
                temp = Math.pow(10,counter);
                powOfTen = (int) temp;
                int digit = Math.floorDiv(term,powOfTen);
                                  
                Integer[] currentArray = lsdArray[digit];
                Integer index = getFreeSpace(currentArray);
                currentArray[index] = array[i];
                lsdArray[digit] = currentArray;


                
    
                }
        
            counter++;           
            return radixSortFunc(flatten(lsdArray),maxDigits,counter);
        }
        else{
            return array;
        }
        

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Integer[] array ={12,23,45,23,166};
        Integer max = getMaxDigits(array);
        Integer[] sortedArray = radixSortFunc(array,max,0);
        for (Integer i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++){
            if (sortedArray[i] != null){
                System.out.println(sortedArray[i]);
            }
            else;
            
        }
        

    }
}
```

i am a begginer to java. i have made this code to sort an array using radix sort. when i run the code with any test array i get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Integer.intValue()" because "array[java.lang.Integer.intValue()]" is null
        at radixSort.radixSortFunc(radixSort.java:52)
        at radixSort.radixSortFunc(radixSort.java:68)
        at radixSort.main(radixSort.java:80)
```

i am a total begginer in java, so please dont tease me if i have made some noob mistake.
it would also be helpful if you give me a shorter way to do this. for example lowering the number of functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you call

`return radixSortFunc(flatten(lsdArray),maxDigits,counter);`

after the first loop.

`lsdArray` is an array almost full of null value (because you didn't initialize them in `Integer[][] lsdArray = new Integer[10][15];`).

So, when you pass in `int term = (array[i] % powOfTen );` with `array[i] = null` you get a NPE.

By the way, you also have an issue with your `getMaxDigits`, it's not returning the maxlength element of your array.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        m = Math.max(max, array[i]);
    }
```

It's returning the length of the last element of your array. Instead you should do something like this

```
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        max = Math.max(max, array[i]);
        m = max;
    }
```

You might also remove var `m` and only use `max` if you want to optimize your function :)

Comment: thank you so much. in the second issue i want the length of the element of the array and not the maximum element. but still thank you very much